# Does there exist a continuous function whose composition with itself is the exponential map?

Tags: analysis

All of the maps

$$
F(x) = x^4 \\
G(x) = \exp (\exp x) \\
H(x) = \sin (\sin x)
$$

can be expressed as the self-compositions of the functions

$$
f(x) = x^2 \\
g(x) = \exp x \\
h(x) = \sin x
$$

So this led me naturally to the question whether other functions can be expressed as the self composition of another function. So this led me naturally to the question:

Does there exist a continous function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(f(x)) = \exp (x)$?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12081/does-the-exponential-function-have-a-square-root